# carrot and potato dumplings question

Tags: potatoes, carrots, dumplings

My question is for potato and carrot dumplings as follows, what sort of binder would you recommend to make it more stable for frying or boiling? I've tried eggs myself, would you recommend flour? if so what kind of flour?

[Potato and carrot dumpling recipe](http://www.food.com/recipe/potato-carrot-dumplings-290821)

Comment: Welcome to seasoned advice! Luckily I can be a bit of help here. I once tried mixing water and (AP) flour (1 tbsp of each) to form a paste and brushing the edges with it, which is what a chef on TV recommended. I was very satisfied with the result. Perhaps you could give it a try.

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid eating anything that mentioned "(the liquid just has to be drinkable & not poisonious to anybody)"

Comment: @Joe I was trying to have people avoid mistakes with the recipe if it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add 1 TBSP of water to 1 TBSP of (AP) flour and mix to form a paste. Brush the edges with a thin layer of the mixture, which was what a chef on a TV cooking show recommended.

Answer (score 3):

You want to squeeze out as much of the water from the carrots and oven dry the potatoes.To make them firmer for frying you could add some panko/homemade breadcrumbs. For simmering add a small amount of flour to the mix.